# Desktop application DB

Tags: c++, xml, sqlite

I my quest to develop a cross platform application I have decided to use C++ with the wxWidgets for the programing language. Now I am facing a dilemma on what local storage solution should I use for a for this application. Any suggestions?

**Note:** I am thinking of using SQLite, but I plan to store images in the DB and I am not sure if this solution will work. If the worse case scenario I can store the image as an XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store images as binary blobs in SQLite.

Comment: I've used SQLite in a similar scenario and it worked like a charm